# php sql query not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page with 3 dropdowns. Team1, Team2 & Venue

[image]

When the user clicks view, I then query the DB returning results for team1 against team2 either playing at home or away or both (depending on users selection)

The code Im using to execute the query follows

```
if($venue = "hometeam"){
        $result= " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` = '$team1' && `awayteam` = '$team2'" or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue = "awayteam"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `awayteam` = '$team1' && `hometeam` = '$team2'"or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue ="all"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE (`hometeam` = '$team1' AND `awayteam` = '$team1') OR (`hometeam` = '$team2' AND `awayteam` = '$team2')"or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

**The Problem**

Regardless if the user selects venue away or both home & away the result returned is always team1 as the hometeam as you can see in the image below:

[image]

In the above example *I selected Team1 as Stormers and Team2 as Sharks, I selected venue away* to display Stormers record against Sharks when they are playing away from home, but as you can see from the image Stormers still gets displayed as the hometeam.

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For one thing, this `if($venue = "hometeam"){` should be using 2x `==` as in `if($venue == "hometeam"){` you're currently "assigning" instead of "comparing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an assignment operation on your **`if`** statements. Make use of `==` instead of `=`

The

```
if($venue = "hometeam"){
```

should be

```
if($venue == "hometeam"){
         //^------ Add one more like this. Do this for your `elseif` too
```

Comment: On `if` **statements** notice the "plural" form? ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by the plural in the IF statment

Comment: You have three. See my answer below to see the differences. @Marilee You have `else if($venue = "awayteam")` while it should be `else if($venue == "awayteam")` and the same for the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently "assigning" instead of "comparing" with your conditional statements. It being in the "plural" form. You have three which should be `==` instead of `=`

`=` is an [**assignment operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), while `==` is a [**comparison operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Missing an extra `=` see arrows `^`

```
if($venue = "hometeam")
           ^

else if($venue = "awayteam")
                ^

else if($venue = "all")
                ^
```

**Rewrite:**

```
if($venue == "hometeam"){
        $result= " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` = '$team1' && `awayteam` = '$team2'" or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue == "awayteam"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `awayteam` = '$team1' && `hometeam` = '$team2'"or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue == "all"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE (`hometeam` = '$team1' AND `awayteam` = '$team1') OR (`hometeam` = '$team2' AND `awayteam` = '$team2')"or die(mysql_error());

    }
```